# Magic Mouse & Bluetooth Keyboard Won't Pair in Lion

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bluetooth, mouse

I have a new macbook pro 15 inch 2011 model. My magic mouse and bt keyboard won't pair. The keyboard doesn't even get detected in the bluetooth settings. How can I get them to work together?

I have bluetooth enabled and tried using Setup Bluetooth Device to pair them.

Comment: Have you tried to connect them with an other Mac? Maybe you ran out of battery or something trivial like that?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is your problem, but it might be and doesn't seem to have been raised elsewhere.  I bought a new MacBook Pro running Lion a few months ago, and found that the (also new) Magic Mouse would not connect automatically—I had to force it to connect after any disconnection from switching off the MM or from rebooting the MacBook.

One of the genii at the Genius Bar, after ½ hour of experimenting and in the process of telling me that Lion would have to be reloaded, suddenly realized that the MM connected upon being clicked.  He stated that he had not run into this before and that it must be a new feature in Lion related to battery preservation.

Bottom line, try a single mouse click to initiate the Bluetooth connection.

Comment: The mouse (or any BT input device) will eventually go to sleep if it gets no input. Clicking will wake it up and cause it to send a beacon to try and find its host. It seems the Apple devices go to sleep very quickly if they are already paired and can't find that device.

Answer (score 1):

I have what is probably the same problem, each time my MBP wakes up the blued daemon crashes (can be seen in Console). AFAIK it has been reported to Apple so I'm waiting for them to fix it. In the mean time I restart the blued daemon each time I notice this problem. The easiest way to do this is by turning bluetooth off and on again via the bluetooth icon.